# Operating on multiple files in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash

Suppose I want to copy (or for that matter, perform any operation on) two files, `dir1/dir2/foo.abc` and `dir1/dir2/bar.xyz`, to the current directory. What I end up doing is this:

```
cp dir1/dir2/bar.xyz dir1/dir2/foo.abc .
```

Is there a less cumbersome way to do the same? I mean something like:

```
cp dir1/dir2/["bar.xyz", "foo.abc"] .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - in fact *very* like that - but with braces rather than square brackets:

```
$ cp -v dir1/dir2/{bar.xyz,foo.abc} ./
'dir1/dir2/bar.xyz' -> './bar.xyz'
'dir1/dir2/foo.abc' -> './foo.abc'
```

See [brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion).

Comment: The tab completion doesn't seem to work inside the braces. Is it the case?

Comment: And also make sure no space exists between the file names: `{bar.xyz,foo.abc}` not `{bar.xyz,  foo.abc}`

Comment: @ibrahim5253 AFAIK tab completion within a brace expansion is not currently supported in `bash` (although it is in `zsh`) - see [How to get tab completion when using curly braces in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181205/how-to-get-tab-completion-when-using-curly-braces-in-bash) for further information.